# My nmcli hotspot broke down since an update, how can I troubleshoot the cause?

Tags: fedora, nmcli

Hey I got a fedora desktop PC in my student dorm that I use as a hotspot.
I use a hotspot created with `nmcli dev wifi hotspot con-name "$name" ssid "$name" password "$password"`

I have been using this for the last few years and had no issues with it. Last week I did some updates and since then most of my devices can't connect to the hotspot anymore.

The Machines I have are: 2 Latops(work and privat), Iphone, and Nintendo switch.

- The Switch still connects with no issues.
- My work laptop did not work.
- My privat laptop did work, but then I updated and it stopped working.
- My Iphone does not connect anymore, I did an update on that but it worked after the update
- My desktop (the one running the hotspot) also did an update, before that there were no issues but I did the updates at the same time
- My laptops can still connect to my iphone hotspot

Im really not sure which device is the cause.
I can connect to the hotspot of my iphone so that makes me think my desktop pc is the reason.
But then I was also able to connect with my laptop before updating.

How can I check what the cause of all this is?
And is it possible to undo `dnf update` transaction? Maybe that would fix my issue

Comment: Until you figure out the root cause, you could `dnf history rollback ...` or `dnf history undo ...` to get back to a previous state.

Comment: Yeah.. after posting I found out about `dnf history` I couldn't rollback however. Some bug with some python scripts. I search and it looks like its a common error.